# Force git push for one file

Tags: git

My repo has two files: G.txt and I.txt. G.txt is edited by other users, while I am the only user who modifies I.txt, and I do not modify G.txt. My usual workflow is as follows:

1. git pull
2. Edit I.txt
3. git add I.txt; git commit -m "message"; git push

I usually run into trouble because between steps 1 & 3, someone else has edited G.txt, so my push fails. People are quite often pushing to G.txt, so it is very difficult to fit my pull and push in before someone else does an edit. Is there a way to force the push to accept my change to I.txt, but not to overwrite the repo's G.txt since others have changed it since my last pull?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm not sure a see a problem here which would preclude just doing a normal merge or rebase to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `git pull --rebase`: that will replay your local (with `l.txt` modification) commit on top of any other commit done on the remote side.

Then push again. No need for forcing the push in that case.

Comment: My issue is that people are constantly pushing to G.txt - so even if I pull, it's usually almost immediately out of date.

Comment: @James Not, pull, pull --rebase followed immediatly by git push. That will work.

Comment: Right - I'll try that.

Comment: @PankajSinghal It can work, but will introduce an necessary merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do a force push. You are not able to push your changes because you don't have the last pushed commit on the remote repo.

A `git pull` will fetch latest changes from repo and merge it into your local repo. Then you can do normal push.

You can also do `git pull --rebase` if you want to avoid a merge commit and apply your changes on top of the latest changes in the remote repo.

Comment: I can git pull, but usually someone has changed G.txt before I can push again, so I never have the last pushed commit.